# Are there any studies on what motivates people to learn artistic languages such as Klingon, Dothraki and the Middle-earth languages?

Tags: reference-request, constructed-languages, motivation

The fictional worlds created in science fiction and fantasy sometimes contain characters that speak languages invented for these fictional worlds. These [fictional languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictional_language) are a category of constructed languages that is known as [artistic languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artistic_language). Some well-known examples:

- [Quenya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quenya), an elven language from J.R.R. Tolkien's Middle-earth,
- [Klingon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klingon_language), from the Star Trek universe (someone even tried to [speak to his son in Klingon for three years](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2009/11/19/darmond-speers-dad-spoke_n_363477.html)),
- [Dothraki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dothraki_language), from J.R.R. Martin's *A Song of Ice and Fire* and its television adaptation *Game of Thrones*,
- [Na'vi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Na'vi_language), from James Cameron's film *Avatar* (see [LearnNavi.org](http://www.learnnavi.org/)).

It is easy to speculate that most people who learn such languages are fans of the fictional worlds for which they were invented—though some people learn them for linguistic reaons—, but are there any *surveys or studies* on this?

Comment: As a side note, I'm learning Klingon not because I'm a star trek fan but because of the unusual syntax and grammar of the language. It's more of a linguistic experiment for me.

Comment: The same is true for many Klingon-speakers. I personally had never seen an episode of Star Trek when I started learning Klingon, and thought Klingons were "the pointy-eared guys". Since then, however, I have seen all of the series and movies.

Answer (score 7):

There are three surveys that come to mind regarding Klingon:

- Stefan Annernäs' [survey of Klingon-speakers](https://web.archive.org/web/19990910145234/http://home1.swipnet.se/%7Ew-12689/survey.htm)
- Judith Hermans' [follow-up sociolinguistic profile of Klingons-speakers](https://www.judion.de/klingon/)
- [Klingon as linguistic capital](https://lup.lub.lu.se/student-papers/search/publication/1355045) by Yens Wahlgren

Comment: [several years later] the first 'survey of Klingon-speakers' you have linked is sadly giving me a 404, if you happen to have an alternative location for it?

Comment: It's still available [on Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20170414080738/http://home1.swipnet.se/~w-12689/survey.htm) :) (And, in case *that* also goes offline one day, it appears that the Royal Library in Stockholm has an archive of all Swipnet pages, but it may not be online due to GDPR.)

Comment: I just put up a page on Klingon academic papers over at Klingonska Akademien which might be of tangential interest if you're looking for more information about Klingon, specifically. http://klingonska.org/academic/

Comment: @zrajm Adding your website as an answer would be welcome, preferably with a short explanation about what the link contains. Alternatively you could edit it into this answer if loghaD is no longer active.